# Why "Inline-block" doesn't work properly in this CSS?

Tags: html, css

Please check the CSS below.

```
 /*rex is the container of ex,ex2,ex3*/
div.rex{
height:200px;
border:0px;
margin:60px auto;
padding: 0;
vertical-align:top;
}

div.ex{
width:34%;
height:200px;
background-color:#4f443a;
display:inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align:top;
}

div.ex2{
width:0.5%;
height:200px;
display:inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align:top;
}


div.ex3{
width:65.5%;
height:200px;
background-color:#7e8547;
display:inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

The result in browser:
[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: @DA thank you for edit. I am a Noob :) I will definitely use fiddle in my next posts. Thank you again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is actually expected behavior in HTML. Because you are using inline-block, any newline character or whitespace you have after the element and before another inline element, will be counted as a space. If you want the blocks to stack side by side like in your picture, your HTML would need to be like this.

```
<div class="rex">
    <div class="ex"></div><div class="ex2"></div><div class="ex3"></div>
</div>
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/afave/2/)

It's not very pretty, but then again, I would recommend using another approach, possibly floating the elements instead.

Refer to here for a more in depth explanation of why this occurs.

[How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: The width he has set is correct, they add up to 100%. Try using his CSS with my HTML and you will see that it works.

Comment: This is the correct answer. FYI for the OP, if you don't want to format the markup this way, you may want to consider floating the DIVs (as block level elements) rather than setting them as inline-block.

Comment: Floating the divs will work well, however be careful if you do not set a height. You might need to clear the floated content before adding anything under it!

Comment: @Tristan. Thank you very much Tristan:) now it work:) I do apologize DA. you asked me to fiddle it but I am not member of it. Thank you.

Comment: I am familiar with HTML for almost 20 years, but I have never thought that newline character between two tags can influence on the layout. Amazing.

Comment: Use `.rex {white-space: nowrap;}`

Comment: You can also comment the space between the inline elements like so: http://jsfiddle.net/a3zst4em/

Answer (score 4):

Just extending answer giving by @Tristan here.

You have repeated the css code unnecessarily. You can minify it by using multiple css like :

```
.ex, .ex2, .ex3 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;  /* no need of height: 200px; here */
}                  /* if you need to extend it to parent height */
                   /* then use height: 100% */
```

**OR**

```
div.rex > div { /* code here */ }
```

You can keep elements side by side by using any of the below approaches:

- [**Using display: table-cell**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/hQn74/)
- [**Using float: left**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/hQn74/1/)
- Using display: inline-block (*[check @Tristan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22397568/1577396)*)

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left;` to your `div.ex`, `div.ex2` and `div.ex3` instead.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P5Bfb/)

UPDATE:
Add `position:absolute` to second and third div if `float` is not a choice.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P5Bfb/2/)

UPDATE 2:
Add this to only 3rd div if you need that space in between.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P5Bfb/5/)

Comment: Should be no need to use floats if using inline-block

Comment: you are doing the overkill with css mate, `position` is kind of *last resort* !! :)

Comment: inline-block is typically an ALTERNATIVE to floating and absolute positioning. If you're using them in combination, there may be something wrong with the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can sue comments like that (this looks little better in code):

```
<div class="rex">
    <div class="ex"><!--
 --></div><div class="ex2"></div><!--
 --><div class="ex3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My trick is to set font-size:0; in the parent element, because it's the font-size that is causing the math to not add up perfectly ( about a 4px overlap per div, depending on screen size ) and causes one div to appear under the other.

```
.rex{
display:block;
font-size:0;
}

.ex{
width:34%;
height:200px;
background-color:#4f443a;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
margin: 0 .5% 0 0; /*small space between divs*/
padding: 0;
font-size:16px; /*restore font size*/
}

.ex2{
width:65.5%;
height:200px;
background-color:#7e8547;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size:16px;
}
```